# Proving the kernel of a group action is the intersection of all the stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

This is part $2$ of a $4$ part question.

[Part $1$ (and links to other parts)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490134/proving-the-stabilizer-of-an-element-in-a-group-is-a-subgroup)

The body of the problem is below:

> If $G \times X \to X$ is a group action then the kernel of the action, $K$, is the intersection of all the stabilizers $$K = \bigcap_{x \in X} \text{stab}_{G}(x)$$

---

Let $\Psi$ be the collection $$\Psi = \{ \text{stab}_{G}(x) \}_{x \in X}$$ Then, by definition of the intersection of a collection of sets, we have: $$\bigcap_{\text{stab}_{G}(x) \in \Psi} \text{stab}_{G}(x) = \{ g \in G \mid g \cdot x = x, \forall x \in X \}$$ Which is exactly the definition of the Kernel of the action.

---

What do you guys think? Does this seem to be alright. The proof seems quite simple. All it is, is an application of the definition of the intersection of a collection of sets, so it seems like there should be more.

Comment: Looks great to me!

Comment: @Arkady, thanks for the verification! Whenever anything is "too easy" I immediately get suspicious. I'm sure I'm not the only one.