# Proving the action of a group on a set is transitive if and only if $G \cdot x = X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

This is part $4$ of a $4$ part question involving various properties of the group action. The link to part $1$ and hence the nexus to all other parts is linked below.

[Part $1$ and links to other parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490134/proving-the-stabilizer-of-an-element-in-a-group-is-a-subgroup)

The body of the problem asks me to show:

> Let $G \times X \to X$ be an action. Prove that the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive if and only if $G \cdot x = X, \text{for some}\ x \in X$

For this problem I have an outline of a proof for the '$\Leftarrow$' part of the proof and would like some feedback on its validity or suggestions on improvement. For the '$\Rightarrow$' portion I have some rough idea of where I want to go/what I want to use for this part but it's quite vague and I'm having trouble really seeing the proof.

---

Obviously as an 'if an only if' statement we need to prove the conclusion from the predicate ($\Rightarrow$) and the predicate from the conclusion ($\Leftarrow$).

$\Leftarrow$: For this part I would like to show equality by two-way inclusion, i.e., that $X \subset G \cdot x$ and $G \cdot x \subset X$. To that end, assume that the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive. That means that $$\forall x,y \in X,\ \exists g \in G \mid g \cdot x = y$$ Take $y \in X$ by transitivity we have $g \cdot x = y$ for some $g \in G$ and $x \in X$ hence $y \in G \cdot x$ and since $y$ was an arbitrary element we can conclude that $X \subset G \cdot x$. Now, let $y' \in G \cdot x$ this means there exists $g' \in G$ and $x \in X$ such that $g' \cdot x = y'$ but by  the definition of transitivity above we know that $x, y' \in X$ since $y'$ was an arbitrary element of $g \cdot x$ we can conclude that $G \cdot x \subset X$. Hence $G \cdot x = X$.

$\Rightarrow$: Assume $G \cdot x = X,\ \text{for some}\ x \in X$. Here I was inclined to appeal to [Part $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490161/proving-the-set-of-orbits-of-the-action-of-a-group-on-a-set-form-a-partition-of?noredirect=1#comment9418953_4490161) and use the fact that the set of orbits of $X$ form a partition of $X$ and use the fact that, by definition of a partition, the union of all equivalence classes (cells of the partition, orbits here) is the whole set. However, that's referring to the *set* of equivalence classes where the orbit of $x$, $G \cdot x$, is just *one* equivalence class. So here this is saying for some element of the set, $x$, the equivalence class of that element is the whole set.

I was hoping to show that this would imply that since $X$ is a partition then every element of $X$ is sent to a distinct equivalence class, where the equivalence class of an element $x$ would be $\{ y \in X \mid x \sim y \} = \{ y \in X \mid g \cdot x = y,\ \text{for some}\ g \in G \}$. However, again, the assumption of $G \cdot x = X$ for some $x \in X$ is implying that every element of the set would be sent to *the same* equivalence class of some element $x \in X$. Some help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have mislabeled the halfs. In what you label $\Leftarrow$, you are assuming transitivity and attempting to prove $G\cdot x = X$, which is the $\Rightarrow$ direction of the statement "action is transitive if and only if $G\cdot x = X$ for some $x\in X$".

Comment: Actually this claim is not quite true. By your definition of transitivity, any group acts transitively on the empty set. But it is not the case that there is some $x \in \varnothing$ such that $G \cdot x = \varnothing$, since indeed there are no elements of $\varnothing$ at all.

To fix this, replace "for some $x \in X$" by "for all $x \in X$".

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: It is probably best to assume $X\neq\varnothing$, as the assumption that $Gx=X$ for all $x$ is much stronger than "there exists $x\in X$ such that $Gx=X$", and makes the problem trivial. (Not that it is terribly hard otherwise, but at least there is something to be done in the "there exists" assumption)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk What Arturo Magidin said, and also, it seems that the definition of a transitivite action most often specifically requires a non-empty set.

Comment: Also, I am not conviced about your reasoning for why x and y' are in X, x in X follows from the definition of G•x, so thats fine,  but the definition of transitivity says that for any two things in X, we can multiply the one by some g to get the other, however you assumed that whenever you multiply something in X by something in G, you still get something in X, but these two statements are different, and so maybe y' in X also follows from the definition of G•x or the definition of "group action" making that inclusion trivial ?(I don't know group theory so just guessing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your labels are backwards as I write this. Also, as noted, there is an unspoken assumption that $X$ is nonempty.

In the $\Rightarrow$ direction, we want to prove that if the action is transitive, then there exists $x\in X$ such that $G\cdot x= X$. Your argument is correct, though note that for *any* action we necessarily have $G\cdot x\subseteq X$ for all $x\in X$, just by definition of what an action is, so you really only need to establish $X\subseteq G\cdot x$ to prove the equality.

In the $\Leftarrow$ direction, assuming that there exists an $x\in X$ such that $G\cdot x = X$, you want to prove transitivity. To that end, let $x',y'\in X$ and you want to show that there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x'=y'$.

Well, we know that $x',y'\in X = G\cdot x$, so there exist $g_1,g_2\in G$ such that $g_1\cdot x = x'$ and $g_2\cdot x = y'$. Can you come up with an element of $G$ that will map $x'$ to $y'$, perhaps by going from $x'$ to $x$ to $y'$?

Comment: Thank you for the correction regarding the 'directions' of the iff statement. Regarding your hint: Well, we know that $g_1$ takes $x$ to $x'$ by left action $$g_1 \cdot x = x'$$ then we can surmise that the element $g^{-1}$ takes $x'$ to $x$ by: $$g^{-1} \cdot (g \cdot x) = (g^{-1}g) \cdot x = e \cdot x = x = g^{-1} \cdot x'$$ All by the properties of an action. Then by assumption we have $G \cdot x = X$ now since $y \in X$ that means there exists $h \in G$ so that $$h \cdot x = y$$ then, since $g_2$ takes $y$ to $y'$ we see the element $$g_2 h g_1^{-1} \in G$$ Takes $x' \to x \to y \to y'$

Comment: Since, by definition of the action: $$(g_2 h g_1^{-1}) \cdot x' = (g_2 h) \cdot (g_1^{-1} \cdot x') = (g_2 h) \cdot x = g_2 \cdot (h \cdot x) = g_2 \cdot y = y'$$ Correct?

Comment: @NumericalDisintegration You are introducing one too many variables. I don't know where you got $y$ from, or why you want to take an extra step to get from $x'$ to $y'$.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I just reread your answer and misread $g_2 \cdot x = y'$ as $g_2 \cdot y = y'$ Which, of course, doesn't make sense since the assumption $G \cdot x = X$ is for the *specific* element $x \in X$. In that case we would have the element $$g_{2}g^{-1} \in G$$ which takes $x'$ to $y'$ and fulfills the requirement for transitivity since: $$(g_{2}g^{-1}) \cdot x' = g_2 \cdot (g^{-1} \cdot x') = g_2 \cdot x = y'$$ By the properties of the action and the fact that $G$ is a group and closed under inverses and products.

Comment: @NumericalDisintegration Yes.